# Keycloak - using admin API to add client roles to users using a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, keycloak

i was trying out the keycloak assign role to a user function using nodejs.i am able to assign a single user using the user id, client id and roles (name,id) single time but i want to write a method where i can get all the user id and get all the role id and name which i already done and basically loop through the assign method so i can assign each user a role one by one until the end of the loop

**Function AssignRole** (works for single user)

```
let userUUID = "0a850afa-dda1-427f-859c-2512dcb55e17"
let kc_clientUUID = "fb1b263c-88d5-4a45-9e18-2098451b5862"
function AssignRole(userUUID, roleId, roleName, kc_clientUUID, kc_accessToken) {
    let urlAssignRole = `${path}/users/${userUUID}/role-mappings/clients/${kc_clientUUID}`;
    return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: urlAssignRole,
        data: [{ id: roleId, name: roleName }],
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${kc_accessToken}`
        }
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Role Assigned!!");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

**function call** working

```
      GetUser(userid, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
           userid = resp.data.map(user => user.id);
            console.log("User Ids");
            console.log(userid);
        })

      GetRole(roleId, roleName, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
           roleId = resp.data.map(role => role.id);
           roleName = resp.data.map(role => role.name);
            console.log("Role Id and Names");
            console.log(roleId);
            console.log(roleName);

        })

         AssignRole(userUUID, "3b178b5b-b323-4bb6-b8d3-a6c2d342fd72", "role4", kc_clientUUID, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {

                })
```

[image]

[image]

now i have a list of users and i have a list of role how can i assign each roles to each users using a loop?

this is my code

**function call** not working

```
        GetUser(userid, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
            userid = resp.data.map(user => user.id);

            GetRole(roleId, roleName, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
                roleId = resp.data.map(role => role.id);
                roleName = resp.data.map(role => role.name);

                // Assign roles to all the user
                AssignRole(userid, roleId, roleName, kc_clientUUID, 
           kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {

                })
            })
        })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a lot about javascript, but based on what you showed:

```
userid = resp.data.map(user => user.id);
```

returns back an array of userid not a single userid, and the same applies to the roles,
so I would say that the following code should work:

```
GetUser(userid, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
            userid = resp.data.map(user => user.id);

            GetRole(roleId, roleName, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
                roleId = resp.data.map(role => role.id);
                roleName = resp.data.map(role => role.name);

                for (var i=0; i < userID.length; i++) {  
                   for (var j=0; j < roleId.length; j++) {
                        AssignRole(userid[i], roleId[j], roleName[j], kc_clientUUID, kc_accessToken) ....
                   }
                }

                
            })
        })
```

Again the syntax might be off, let me know.